# Somar horas como Moment.Js

Tags: javascript, json, data, momentjs

Eu tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não quero trabalhar com data e hora juntos, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade do Moment.js somar apenas as horas, sem necessariamente precisar da data na variável obtida.

Bom, quando eu gero minha query trago minhas horas baseada nas datas registradas no banco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu controller está atualmente assim:

```
public function get()
{
    $user = $_SESSION['nome'];

    $this->load->model('trackerModel');
    $query = $this->trackerModel->get($user)->result_array();

    foreach($query as $element){
        $result[$element['date']][] = $element;

    }   

    $data = [];
    foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        $data[] = [
            'date'=> $key,
            'item' => $value
        ];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

E o meu JSON, assim:

```
[{"date":"26-08-2019","item":[{"id":"78","hrStart":"11:09:00","hrEnd":"12:09:00","hrWork":"01:00:00","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"26-08-2019","cliente":"Marcelo","projeto":"Aplicativo Mobile","pacote":"Aplicativo Mobile","type":"Non-Billable","descri":"","hrTotal":""},{"id":"82","hrStart":"04:00:00","hrEnd":"07:00:00","hrWork":"03:00:00","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"26-08-2019","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","pacote":"TimeTrack","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","descri":"","hrTotal":""}]}]
```

Daí vem minha dúvida, eu quero pegar essas `hrWork` e somar, porém quero apenas o resultado total de cada data, para eu poder mostrar ao usuário o quanto ele trabalhou por dia. Isso é possível?

Comment: const endTime = moment(hrStart, 'HH:mm:ss').add(durationInMinutes, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro precisamos entender dois conceitos importantes. Considere as duas frases abaixo:

- comecei a trabalhar às 8 horas da manhã
- hoje trabalhei por 8 horas seguidas

No primeiro caso, "8 horas" refere-se ao **horário** (um momento específico do dia). Tudo bem que ele precisa de "da manhã" para não ser ambíguo (poderia ser 8 da noite), mas o fato é que está se referindo a um momento específico.

No segundo caso, "8 horas" refere-se à **duração** (uma quantidade de tempo). Não é dito que horas comecei a trabalhar. É somente a quantidade de tempo, sem qualquer relação com horários.

Esses dois conceitos **não são a mesma coisa**. Um horário (hora, minuto, segundo, frações de segundo) refere-se a um momento específico de um dia. Durações são apenas quantidades de tempo, que existem por si só, sem estarem atrelados a uma data e hora específicas.

O que confunde é o fato de que ambos (tanto horários quanto durações) usam exatamente as mesmas palavras (dias, horas, minutos, etc), e muitas vezes são escritos da mesma maneira (um relógio mostra "08:00:00" quando é 8 da manhã, um cronômetro mostra "08:00:00" quando a contagem do tempo atinge oito horas).

Outro ponto que pode - erroneamente - nos fazer pensar que horários e durações são a mesma coisa é que, embora sejam conceitos diferentes, eles podem estar relacionados. Se eu calcular a diferença entre duas datas e/ou horários, o resultado é uma duração (sabendo a data/hora que começou e que terminou, consigo calcular quanto tempo durou), e se eu somar uma data/hora com uma duração, o resultado é outra data/hora (sabendo a data/hora que começou e quanto tempo durou, consigo calcular a data/hora que terminou).

---

Dito isso, os seus campos `hrStart` e `hrEnd` são horários (a hora em que começou e terminou o trabalho), enquanto o campo `hrWork` é uma duração (a quantidade de tempo trabalhado).

<sup>*Então o primeiro ponto é que `hrWork` não deveria ser guardado como um `TIME` no banco de dados, pois ele não é um horário. Talvez devesse ser guardado como um número, contendo a quantidade total de minutos (ou de segundos), por exemplo. Mas enfim, este é um problema à parte, vamos ao cálculo em si.*</sup>

Felizmente, [o Moment.js possui suporte à durações](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), então bastaria obtê-las do seu JSON e ir somando. Para mostrar o resultado em um formato mais amigável, você pode baixar a [versão com *locales*](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js):

```js
let json = [{"date":"26-08-2019","item":[{"id":"78","hrStart":"11:09:00","hrEnd":"12:09:00","hrWork":"01:00:00","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"26-08-2019","cliente":"Marcelo","projeto":"Aplicativo Mobile","pacote":"Aplicativo Mobile","type":"Non-Billable","descri":"","hrTotal":""},{"id":"82","hrStart":"04:00:00","hrEnd":"07:00:00","hrWork":"03:00:00","nome_user":"Diego ","date":"26-08-2019","cliente":"Carlos","projeto":"TimeSheet","pacote":"TimeTrack","type":"programa\u00e7\u00e3o","descri":"","hrTotal":""}]}];

let duracaoTotal = moment.duration(0);
// percorrer os itens
json.forEach(obj => {
    obj.item.forEach(i => {
        duracaoTotal.add(moment.duration(i.hrWork));
    });
});
// usar o locale "pt" (português)
console.log(`Total: ${duracaoTotal.locale("pt").humanize()}`);

// ou formate o valor manualmente (nesse caso não precisa da versão com locales)
console.log(duracaoTotal.hours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
            duracaoTotal.minutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
            duracaoTotal.seconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'));

// também é possível obter o total em minutos
console.log(duracaoTotal.asMinutes()); // 240
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Infelizmente não existe ainda um método similar à `format` para durações ([como existe para datas](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)), então você pode usar a versão com *locales* para exibir para o usuário em um formato mais amigável, ou formatar manualmente, caso precise de um formato específico.

Mas para gravar no banco, é melhor guardar um único valor numérico (como o total de minutos, por exemplo). No caso acima, o total (retornado pelo método `asMinutes()`) é de 240 minutos (que equivale a uma duração de 4 horas), e este valor poderia ser guardado em um campo numérico (para restaurar a duração, bastaria fazer `moment.duration(240, 'minutes')`, por exemplo). Usar um tipo `TIME` (que representa um horário) para guardar uma duração não é o ideal.

---

O código acima faz um *loop* e soma tudo que tem no JSON. Mas no seu caso, você que separar por data, então basta fazer uma pequena adaptação:

```js
// versão simplificada, com os campos que vou usar, apenas para fins didáticos
let json = [
    {"date" : "26-08-2019",
     "item" : [
         {"hrWork":"01:00:00","date":"26-08-2019"}, 
         {"hrWork":"03:00:00","date":"26-08-2019"}
     ]
    },
    {"date" : "27-08-2019",
     "item" : [
         {"hrWork":"02:00:00","date":"27-08-2019"}, 
         {"hrWork":"01:30:00","date":"27-08-2019"}
     ]
    }
];

let totais = {};
// percorrer os itens
json.forEach(obj => {
    obj.item.forEach(i => {
        if (! totais[i.date]) {
            totais[i.date] = moment.duration(0);
        }
        totais[i.date].add(moment.duration(i.hrWork));
    });
});

Object.keys(totais).forEach(d => {
    let duracaoTotal = totais[d];
    console.log(`Total do dia ${d}: ` +
                duracaoTotal.hours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
                duracaoTotal.minutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
                duracaoTotal.seconds().toString().padStart(2, '0'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Repare que agora não usei a versão com *locales*, e sim o `moment.min.js`, pois não usei o método `humanize` (em vez disso formatei o valor manualmente).

E agora foi criado um objeto `totais`, cujas chaves são as datas e os valores são os respectivos totais de cada dia.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode calcular a diferença em minutos entre as "duas horas" e depois adicionar a diferença na nova hora.

```
// hora inicial
var hrStart = '10:00';
// hora final
var hrEnd = '11:02';
// hora que você vai somar
var hfFoo = '20:00';

// Calcula a diferença em minutos entre os dois tempos 
var diffInMinutes = moment(hrEnd,"HH:mm").diff(moment(hrStart,"HH:mm"), 'minutes');

// Adiciona os minutos na hora desejada
var totalTime = moment(hfFoo, 'HH:mm').add(diffInMinutes, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');

console.log(totalTime);

// 21:02
```

Comment: Certo, porem minhas horas ja vem formatada do banco... Queria já somar elas com o moment se possivel

Comment: Formatadas como?

Comment: elas vem no formato hh:mm, porem queria fazer uma soma delas, dentro de um for, teria como?

Comment: Dá sim, vou alterar a resposta.

Comment: Beleza, fico no aguardo aqui, obrigado!

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade verifica se agora resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Me deu um bom norte, porem assim, no meu db eu puxo as horas pela data, ai se o cara fizer 3 serviços com horas diferentes ele me gera a hora trabalhada de cada serviço... eu queria somar essas horas trabalhadas, pra por na minha tabela la na view... Tem como fazer isso ? Tipo eu passar por um for, ele armazenar a data e somar com as outras que vem ?

Comment: Cara edita sua pergunta e tenta exemplificar o que você realmente quer, assim fica meio difícil de te ajudar.

Comment: Dei uma editada, vê se tu consegue entender o que quero fazer, mais uma vez, obrigado!